# AlarmManager in Lollipop runs only after Reboot

Tags: android, alarmmanager

In my app, I have an AlarmManager set up that runs every 5 mins, triggering a service. However I find that in Lollipop phones, it works only after I reboot the phone. If I do not reboot the phone, the AlarmManager never runs. Please let me know if you might be able to help me out with some hints. Appreciate your help.

```
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 120);

        Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(appContext, CheckConnReceiver.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent
        = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(appContext, 0, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // create the object
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) appContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                  calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 300000, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: What is your target API? @Krishnan VS